# Python - Doing double as much in a single loops vs 2 loops

Tags: python, loops

This is probably a silly question but what is the benefit of having a setup such as:

```
for i in list:
 do task 1
 do task 2
```

vs

```
for i in list:
 do task 1 

for j in list:
 do task 2
```

I presume there is no performance difference between the two for large lists, but is there any convention as to which is better. I guess 2 can be parallelised more easily and is easier to catch errors, but has the redundancy of effectively a repeated line

Comment: There is almost no performance difference, but I'd rather go with the 1st convention, it's more concise, clear, doesn't unnecessarily use a second variable, and you can catch errors just so easily with print statements.

Comment: Almost none, because there is only a difference in the iteration activity, the tasks are split anyway. It would be equivalent to the loop in 1st example, and then an empty loop. That empty loop is like almost negligible even for 10000 elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is hardly any *performance* difference between the two because the *same number of tasks* is being performed by each, but there is a logical difference. The first alternates between task 1 and task 2. The second piece of code does task 1 for each item in the list, before doing each task 2.

I would choose between the two solely on the basis of this logical difference.

Comment: That's assuming, that task1() actually modified the content of the list, then yes, there is a logical difference.

Comment: Even if task1 did not modify `list`, the order of operations is different.

Comment: Of course, but the result is still the same in that case. Well I'm assuming the author knows what he wants to do, and asks this question consciously, knowing that to his problem the two are logically equivalent.

Comment: If task1 is to print 'foo', and task 2 is to print 'bar', the result would not be the same :)

Comment: Okay, okay, I was maybe not precise, but I think he wouldn't be asking what's the difference in that case ;)